# Multiple Conditions or Statements in Short Hand if-else statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

I recently saw this if-else short hand in python and wondered is there a way to include multiple conditions and block statements in the if-else shorthand, if required.

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
print(a) if (a>b) else print("Equal") if (a==b) else print(b)
```

Can Something like the below code can be written in short-hand?

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())

if (a>b):
 print(a)
elif(a==b):
 print("Equal") 
elif(b>0) and (a>0):
 c=a+b
 print(c)
else:
 print("#")
```

PS: The code is arbitrary just to include multiple conditions and statements.

Comment: That will become a very long and difficult-to-read statement. It's not advised you use the short hand conditional statements for complex conditions.

Comment: A conditional expression is just syntactic sugar, it compiles to the exact same thing as the corresponding statement. So as long as you don't need / use a statement in one of the branches you can always convert from one to the other. It just requires some flipping around since the "taken" branch appears before the test in the expression. Not unlike for loops and list comprehensions.

Comment: there is no `elif` in the shorthand form, so (as can be seen in @Mehadi's answer) you have to combine a series of `<this> if <cond> else <that>` clauses into one big expression... but don't do that because it's unreadable bad code style (I am not criticising the answer though)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write your block of code in a single line then this should work -

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())

print(a) if (a>b) else print("Equal") if (a==b) else print(a+b) if (b>0) and (a>0) else print("#")
```

Although this doesn't reduce the codes in the original block of yours.